# HighCharts Heatmap yAxis title

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

When I create a Heatmap chart in HighCharts, I cannot seem to add a vertical, yAxis label.

For example, for xAxis I have:

```
title: {
enabled: true,
text: 'my axis'}
```

But the same approach does not work for y. I've demonstrated this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hendrkle/zgjevotx/

For example, it could say "day of week" on the vertical axis.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your y-axis code, made more readable, is:

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
        enabled: true,
        text: 'my axis'
    },
    categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
    title: null
}
```

Note how you are setting title, then setting it to null afterwards.

Remove `title: null` and it should work perfectly.

Comment: I'd been staring at this for half an hour and didn't spot it. Thank you @Ondkloss!

Answer (score 1):

1. As mentioned above, you are setting `title:null` after declaring it above. Remove that second declaration.
2. Additionally, your `marginBottom:40` is hiding the label in the svg. Remove that declaration.

You can see the fix here: http://jsfiddle.net/85nmcfx0/ .